# Difference in debug symbols in arm gcc/gdb

Tags: arm

I am a newbie in ARM controllers. When I started the debugging, I noticed something odd. I was supposed to get a interrupt and it should end up in the Default_Handler. When I look in to the source window, it seems working as expected. But on the disassembly window, it is showing that the PC is on WWDG_IRQHandler. According to the map file both  the Default_Handler and WWDG_IRQHandler are located in the same address (0x080007f8).

I am using STM32F407 with GNU ARM compiler.

Please take a look at the screenshot.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdXMi.png)

```
g_pfnVectors:
  .word  _estack
  .word  Reset_Handler
  .word  NMI_Handler
  .word  HardFault_Handler
  .word  MemManage_Handler
  .word  BusFault_Handler
  .word  UsageFault_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  SVC_Handler
  .word  DebugMon_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  PendSV_Handler
  .word  SysTick_Handler



  /* External Interrupts */
  .word     WWDG_IRQHandler                  
  .word     PVD_IRQHandler                   
  .word     TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler            
  .word     RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler              
  .word     FLASH_IRQHandler                 
  .word     RCC_IRQHandler                   
  .word     EXTI0_IRQHandler                 
  .word     EXTI1_IRQHandler                 
  .word     EXTI2_IRQHandler                 
  .word     EXTI3_IRQHandler                 
  .word     EXTI4_IRQHandler                 
  .word     DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA1_Stream1_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler          
  .word     ADC_IRQHandler                   
  .word     CAN1_TX_IRQHandler               
  .word     CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler              
  .word     CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler              
  .word     CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler              
  .word     EXTI9_5_IRQHandler               
  .word     TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQHandler         
  .word     TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler         
  .word     TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler    
  .word     TIM1_CC_IRQHandler               
  .word     TIM2_IRQHandler                  
  .word     TIM3_IRQHandler                  
  .word     TIM4_IRQHandler                  
  .word     I2C1_EV_IRQHandler               
  .word     I2C1_ER_IRQHandler               
  .word     I2C2_EV_IRQHandler               
  .word     I2C2_ER_IRQHandler               
  .word     SPI1_IRQHandler                  
  .word     SPI2_IRQHandler                  
  .word     USART1_IRQHandler                
  .word     USART2_IRQHandler                
  .word     USART3_IRQHandler                
  .word     EXTI15_10_IRQHandler             
  .word     RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler             
  .word     OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQHandler           
  .word     TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQHandler        
  .word     TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQHandler         
  .word     TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler    
  .word     TIM8_CC_IRQHandler               
  .word     DMA1_Stream7_IRQHandler          
  .word     FSMC_IRQHandler                  
  .word     SDIO_IRQHandler                  
  .word     TIM5_IRQHandler                  
  .word     SPI3_IRQHandler                  
  .word     UART4_IRQHandler                 
  .word     UART5_IRQHandler                 
  .word     TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler              
  .word     TIM7_IRQHandler                  
  .word     DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA2_Stream1_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA2_Stream4_IRQHandler          
  .word     ETH_IRQHandler                   
  .word     ETH_WKUP_IRQHandler              
  .word     CAN2_TX_IRQHandler               
  .word     CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler              
  .word     CAN2_RX1_IRQHandler              
  .word     CAN2_SCE_IRQHandler              
  .word     OTG_FS_IRQHandler                
  .word     DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA2_Stream6_IRQHandler          
  .word     DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler          
  .word     USART6_IRQHandler                
  .word     I2C3_EV_IRQHandler               
  .word     I2C3_ER_IRQHandler               
  .word     OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQHandler        
  .word     OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQHandler         
  .word     OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQHandler           
  .word     OTG_HS_IRQHandler                
  .word     DCMI_IRQHandler                  
  .word     CRYP_IRQHandler                  
  .word     HASH_RNG_IRQHandler              
  .word     FPU_IRQHandler                   
       

/*******************************************************************************
*
* Provide weak aliases for each Exception handler to the Default_Handler.
* As they are weak aliases, any function with the same name will override
* this definition.
*
*******************************************************************************/
                  
.weak      NMI_Handler
.thumb_set NMI_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      HardFault_Handler
.thumb_set HardFault_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      MemManage_Handler
.thumb_set MemManage_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      BusFault_Handler
.thumb_set BusFault_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      UsageFault_Handler
.thumb_set UsageFault_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      SVC_Handler
.thumb_set SVC_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      DebugMon_Handler
.thumb_set DebugMon_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      PendSV_Handler
.thumb_set PendSV_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      SysTick_Handler
.thumb_set SysTick_Handler,Default_Handler

.weak      WWDG_IRQHandler
.thumb_set WWDG_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      PVD_IRQHandler
.thumb_set PVD_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler
.thumb_set RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      FLASH_IRQHandler
.thumb_set FLASH_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      RCC_IRQHandler
.thumb_set RCC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI0_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI0_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI2_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI3_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI4_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA1_Stream1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler
              
.weak      DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      ADC_IRQHandler
.thumb_set ADC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN1_TX_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN1_TX_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI9_5_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI9_5_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM1_CC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM2_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM3_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM4_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      I2C1_EV_IRQHandler
.thumb_set I2C1_EV_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      I2C1_ER_IRQHandler
.thumb_set I2C1_ER_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      I2C2_EV_IRQHandler
.thumb_set I2C2_EV_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      I2C2_ER_IRQHandler
.thumb_set I2C2_ER_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      SPI1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set SPI1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      SPI2_IRQHandler
.thumb_set SPI2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      USART1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set USART1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      USART2_IRQHandler
.thumb_set USART2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      USART3_IRQHandler
.thumb_set USART3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI15_10_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI15_10_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler
.thumb_set RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQHandler
.thumb_set OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM8_CC_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM8_CC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA1_Stream7_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA1_Stream7_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      FSMC_IRQHandler
.thumb_set FSMC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      SDIO_IRQHandler
.thumb_set SDIO_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM5_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM5_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      SPI3_IRQHandler
.thumb_set SPI3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      UART4_IRQHandler
.thumb_set UART4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      UART5_IRQHandler
.thumb_set UART5_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      TIM7_IRQHandler
.thumb_set TIM7_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream4_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      ETH_IRQHandler
.thumb_set ETH_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      ETH_WKUP_IRQHandler
.thumb_set ETH_WKUP_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN2_TX_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN2_TX_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN2_RX1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN2_RX1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CAN2_SCE_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CAN2_SCE_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      OTG_FS_IRQHandler
.thumb_set OTG_FS_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream6_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream6_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      USART6_IRQHandler
.thumb_set USART6_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      I2C3_EV_IRQHandler
.thumb_set I2C3_EV_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      I2C3_ER_IRQHandler
.thumb_set I2C3_ER_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQHandler
.thumb_set OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQHandler
.thumb_set OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQHandler
.thumb_set OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      OTG_HS_IRQHandler
.thumb_set OTG_HS_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      DCMI_IRQHandler
.thumb_set DCMI_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      CRYP_IRQHandler
.thumb_set CRYP_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      HASH_RNG_IRQHandler
.thumb_set HASH_RNG_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      FPU_IRQHandler
.thumb_set FPU_IRQHandler,Default_Handler
```

Comment: what does your vector table look like.  what interrupt/exception are you trying to fire, etc....

Comment: @old_timer, I have added the vector table in the question. Please look at the screenshot also. I was trying to fire the SysTick timer interrupt. I am getting that interrupt, but when I don't use the SysTick_Handler() function, I should end up in default handler right? My doubt is in the disassembly window, the PC is at WWDG_IRQHandler(). But on the source window, it seems correct. Please take a look at the screenshot attached with the question.

Comment: [From the GNU assembler manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html): "`.thumb_set`:

    This performs the equivalent of a `.set` directive in that it creates a symbol which is an alias for another symbol (possibly not yet defined)..."  So your `.thumb_set WWDG_IRQHandler,Default_Handler` has precisely the effect of making `WWDG_IRQHandler` refer to the same address as `Default_Handler`.  The `.weak` means this can be overridden if you redefine `WWDG_IRQHandler` elsewhere in your program, but apparently you do not.  What did you expect to have happen here?

Comment: one handler per, using the .weak etc just makes it harder to read, what does the disassembly/dump show?  that is what matters.

Comment: The `.weak` is intended to provide a default functionality (uncontrolled execution) when interrupts are not provided.  The large 3rd idiom of `.weak` and `.set` are to make all undefined interrupts use the default handler.  It is explained by the comment in the code.  Everything is by design and you have no question in your question.  Some how you have enabled an interrupt that is normally disabled; you need to provide the definition for that interrupt.  It is one of the aliases (weak/set).  The default handler is an infinite loop which stops random code from executing.